# Slow down rs232, 9600 (locked) to 300 for vintage printer

Tags: arduino, serial, rs232, buffer

I have an old GE terminal (late 70s) that I'm trying to use and an old serial printer. The RS-232 port is locked at 9600 baud but my TI Silent 700 (late 70s) is 300 baud max. I've tried to Google printer buffer ideas but came up with nothing.

I was thinking I might be able to make a buffer using an Arduino but figured before I pursuing Arduino shields I'd ask for ideas.

Comment: Your idea is the best you can think of, provided you have enough knowledge to implement it. It should be not difficult to use an Arduino (or other special, simple uC hardware) to make the buffer.

Comment: Does the arduino have enough memory to buffer everything you need?

Comment: @Colin: If you use flow control it doesn't matter how small the buffer is.  You buffer what you can at high speed, set the flow control to tell the PC to wait, then you dump your buffer to the slow device.  Set flow control to accept data again, and repeat.

Comment: @JRE Good point, as long as the terminal supports it

Comment: Ok, anyone know about a something I can buy or maybe  a phrase I can Google  for such a device?  I have tried googling "Arduino serial printer buffer" but results are as expected. "serialPrint()"

Comment: Down convert UART speeds and use CTS RTS for flow control with DTR DSR high